# Add key values to dictionary without key value pairs being associated to one another

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I've created a dictionary of different keys and different values. When I update the values for one key, all the values update and are equal. I don't understand why that is. I don't understand why the values of each key are pointing to the same memory location especially when they were created at different times.

I've tried using the update methods.
I've tried assigning values by doing `diction['new_value']= 'key_value'`.
I've tried the `from_keys()`.

```
def transform(self, rows):
    #Rows are a row from a csv, tsv, or txt file and I'm splitting them by white space, tabs, or commas. I've created an inherited function that does that for me called split_line.
    data = self.split_line(rows)
    for idx, column in enumerate(data):
        if idx != 0:
            if self.metadata_types[idx].lower() == 'numeric':
                column = round(float(column), 3)
            elif self.metadata_types[idx].lower() == 'group':
                if column not in self.uniqueValues:
                    self.uniqueValues.append(column)
        annotation =self.header[idx]
        self.annotation_subdocs[annotation]['value'].append(column)


def create_annotation_subdocs(self):
    annotation_subdocs = dict()
    #For ever value in the header I want to create a new dictionary with the key being the header value
    for idx, value in enumerate(self.header):
        if value == 'name':
            self.annotation_subdocs[value]= create_metadata_subdoc('text', idx, 'cells')
            print(id(annotation_subdocs[value]))
        elif value in ('x', 'y', 'z'):
            self.annotation_subdocs[value] = create_metadata_subdoc(value, idx, 'coordinates')
            print(id(annotation_subdocs[value]))
        else:
            self.annotation_subdocs[value]=create_metadata_subdoc(value, idx, 'annotations')
            print(id(annotation_subdocs[value]))

def create_metadata_subdoc(name, idx, header_value_type, *, value=[], subsampled_annotation=None):
return {
    'name': name,
    'array_index': idx,
    'value': value,
    'array_type': header_value_type,
    'subsampled_annotation': subsampled_annotation,
    'subsamp_threashold': "",
}
```

I expect the values for each key to do different. Instead all the values are updating at the same time even though I'm accessing specific keys.

Comment: You need to make a [mcve]

Comment: What is `diction`? What is the dictionary causing the issue in your code? You need to give enough details that we can reproduce your issue.